# The method is not applicable for arguments

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface and 2 classes that implement it and a third class that has 2 methods- one which gets the first class object as parameter, and the second one gets the other. I have a vector that contains both types of objects and I want to use the third function's method on each element without having to cast the type, as I don't know what type each vector element is. How can I do that? This is the code:

```
public interface Transport {
}

public class Car implements Transport {
}

public class Bike implements Transport {
}

public class Operation {
    public void operation(Car c) {
        System.out.println("1");
   }

   public void operation(Bike b) {
       System.out.println("2");
   }
```

And in main I have this:

```
Transport[] t = new Transport[3];
t[0] = new Car();
t[1] = new Bike();
t[2] = new Car();
Operation op = new Operation();
op.operation(t[0]); // here I get the error - method not applicable for arguments
```

This code is a simplified version of what I did, in order to be easier to read, there aren't only three elements and they are created in a for loop based on what input it gets.

Comment: Put the operation() method in the Transport class, and override it Car and in Bike. That's what polymorphism is about: `t[0].operation()`. Rename it to `move()`, and rename the Transport interface to `Vehicle` to understand the concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use method overloading in a situation when the compiler does not know the run-time type of the expression.

Specifically, the compiler does not know if `t[0]` is a `Car` or a `Bike`, so it issues an error.

You can fix this by inverting the call: give `Transport` a method to call `operate`, and call it instead:

```
public interface Transport {
    void performOperation(Operation op);
}

public class Car implements Transport {
    public void performOperation(Operation op) { op.operate(this); }
}

public class Bike implements Transport {
    public void performOperation(Operation op) { op.operate(this); }
}
```

Now you can make a call as follows:

```
Transport[] t = new Transport[3];
t[0] = new Car();
t[1] = new Bike();
t[2] = new Car();
Operation op = new Operation();
t[0].performOperation(op);
```

This technique is commonly known as the [*Visitor Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: @davidxxx I don't see how they mix up in the same structure: `Transport` is a visitable, while `Operation` is a visitor.

Comment: Your way is a specific form of the visitor pattern :) In fact, what I would mean is it just misses the interface behind the visitor implementation that allows visited elements to accept any visitor implementations. Again, fine example.